# Wso2 IS Clustering (LoadBalancing/Failover)

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am looking into clustering of the Wso2 IS in [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+Identity+Server+5.1.0+and+5.2.0).

1. Does it really serve the Failover case?
2. How many nodes are needed for a minimum load-balance scenario?
3. As per the documentation, clustering is configuration between 5.1 & 5.2. Isn't it possible to achieve with same versions / much older versions?

Comment: question No-2. It depend on your load. But you need minimum two nodes to start load balancing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation explains how to create two node cluster with active state (both nodes are active) and fronted by a load balancer.

If you need a failover scenario, you can have a node in active state (assuming one node can serve all of your requests) and one node in passive state. If active node fails, load balancer has to direct the traffic to the passive node. So this will serve the failover scenario. You don't need to do any configuration changes in IS level for this. This can be configured in the load balancer level.

Documentation explains clustering for IS 5.1.0 and 5.2.0 versions, but not between these 2 versions. Cluster can be created with only 1 version of server nodes, but not with nodes of different versions.

Comment: thanks mate. Point accepted. question arose is because if the User-Store from v4x and now if I install 5x, do I have to migrate everything from 4x to 5x, doesn't the clustering of both will yield me the same way of processing?

Comment: Yes you have to migrate. Clustering of different versions wont work.